# Don't understand why I'm getting a NameError in my class definition

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, nameerror

I'm making a simple products inventory app with Tkinter and I'm getting a `NameError` on line 10 as shown in the traceback.

```
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3

class Product:
    def __init__(self, window):
        self.wind = window
        self.wind.title("Products inventory")

    frame = LabelFrame(self.wind, text  = 'Register a new product')
    frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 3, pady = 20)

    Label(frame, text = 'Name: ').grid(row = 1, column = 0)
    self.name = Entry(frame)
    self.name.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = Tk()
    application = Product(window)
    window.mainloop()
```

The error displayed is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Joaquin\Desktop\Python apps\Products\main.py", line 5, in <module>
    class Product:
  File "C:\Users\Joaquin\Desktop\Python apps\Products\main.py", line 10, in Product
    frame = LabelFrame(self.wind, text  = 'Register a new product')
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

Comment: This line is outside of the scope of `__init__` and therfore `self` is not defined there. I guess you should indent all lines of the class inside the `__init__`. Sadly, I don't have much experience with `tkinter`, but maybe you want `Product` to inherit from `Tk` or something like this

Comment: Most of your `__init__` method isn't indented enough to put it inside the method body, so of course `self` and `window` are out of scope for that code.  Just fix your indentation.

Comment: Also, it shouldn't be necessary to import `tkinter` more than once.  Just decide how you want to access its contents, and keep that `import` (and delete the other).

Comment: Python issue, not tkinter issue. `self` is what should be passed into any methods defined in your class. However, everything after your `__init__()` is just in the middle of the class and not inside of a function as it should be.

Answer (score 1):

It is an indentation problem, part of your code is directly in the class body instead of the `__init__` body:

```
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3

class Product:
    def __init__(self, window):
        self.wind = window
        self.wind.title("Products inventory")

        frame = LabelFrame(self.wind, text  = 'Register a new product')
        frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 3, pady = 20)

        Label(frame, text = 'Name: ').grid(row = 1, column = 0)
        self.name = Entry(frame)
        self.name.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

window = Tk()
application = Product(window)
window.mainloop()
```